# Loading images with image_dataset_from_directory() from keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

The folder of images has the following structure:

```
train/
...batch0/
......file00.jpg
......file01.jpg
...batch1/
......file10.jpg
......file11.jpg
```

Names of directories `batch0` and `batch1` are not labels, labels are in a separate file. The problem is to load these images into a dataset. Function `image_dataset_from_directory('/batch0')`, `image_dataset_from_directory('/batch1')` doesn't work.

Error:

```
ValueError: Expected the lengths of labels to match the number of files in the target directory. len(labels) is 2 while we found 0 files in ../train/batch0/.
```

Comment: Why are you separating the images into batches in the folder itself? What is the error it throws?

Comment: I have two unsuccessful situations and one successful. 
1) `image_dataset_from_directory('../train/batch0')

Found 0 files belonging to 0 classes.`

2) `labels_list=[0, 1]

image_dataset_from_directory(train_dir, labels=labels_list)

ValueError: Expected the lengths of labels to match the number of files in the target directory. len(labels) is 2 while we found 0 files in ../train/batch0/.`

3) Successful situation:
`image_dataset_from_directory('../train/')

Found 4 files belonging to 2 classes.`

Comment: Ah you need to use the relative path, like in the successful case but the thing is that `image_dataset_from_directory` assumes that the directories are different classes not batches.

Comment: There is mode for `image_dataset_from_directory`, you can turn it on/off by the parameter `labels`. labels:  Either "inferred" (labels are generated from the directory structure), or a list/tuple of integer labels of the same size as the number of image files found in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this should be fixed in tf-nightly version.
The error message has been updated to,

> If you wish to get a dataset that only contains images (no labels),
> pass `labels_mode=None`.

Instead of `labels=None`, pass `label_mode=None`

```
train/
...batch0/
......file00.jpg
......file01.jpg
...batch1/
......file10.jpg
......file11.jpg

import pathlib
data_dir = pathlib.Path('/content/train/')

import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 16
img_height = 180
img_width = 180
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  label_mode=None,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Output

```
Found 4 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 3 files for training.
```

Comment: I just want to add that this works for R as well. Just use `label_mode = NULL`